# 16.04 - Cant login or do ctrl-atl-f1

Tags: login

I am currently using version 16.04. Yesterday my ubuntu was working fine. Everything was good. Then I switched to Window 10 to do some stuff (just for error reproduction). When I switched back to Ubuntu, I got black border errors. I thought it was Nvidia driver problems so I remove Nvidia and reboot to reinstall it. I ran this command:

```
chmod u+x NVIDIA.....run (NVIDIA....run is a driver installer that I downloaded from NVIDIA)
sudo ./NVIDIA.....run
```

When the installer was working, I interrupted it by keep pressing power button. When I restarted, I cannot login or do ctrl-atl-f[1, 2, 6] anymore. When I pressed ctrl-atl-f[1, 2, 6], a blank screen appeared and I can't switch back by ctrl-alt-f7.

Now I'm so frustrated. I didn't back up my files. Please help me, I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally did this 5 minutes ago, lol. ironic. The reinstall is probably no good if it was interrupted. Uninstall is like this, Reboot into the multi-use target by setting it as default 'systemctl set-default multi-user.target' and run 'NVIDIA...run --uninstall' then set target back to graphical.target and reboot again. You should reboot back into the nouveau driver.

Comment: where should I type in that line "systemctl set-default multi-user.target" ? I cant login and cant use ctrl-alt-f1.

Comment: Try booting into a live install, mount your old system under /mnt, chroot into it with 'sudo chroot /mnt' and then go ahead and run it. Chrooting into your old system is like having a terminal to it, you just got it using another install.

Comment: Thanks I have resolved my problem. I did follow your instruction to mount my old system under /mnt. But after that, I back up my important file to my Window storage and I then decided to install a new system again :-?. This probably not a good idea. But like I didnt entirely get your solution like why running NVIDIA...run --uninstall will resolve my problem. Anyway, thanks for supporting me.

Comment: It would have switched your system back to the open source video driver, that most likely would have allowed you to see the screen and log in. :)

Comment: but I will run that command in USB live install, so how can it affect my old system :-? as the directory is different. Also in my old system my "/home" and "/" is mount from different devices.

Comment: That's ok. As long as you have everything from your old system mounted in the relevant directories, /home from your old system is mounted at /mnt/home, when you run 'chroot /mnt' it will lock you into that area of the filesystem and everything you do will then become as if you are working in your system.

Comment: Oh that all makes sense now. Thats why I need to chroot it.  Thanks.

Comment: That's correct, and you're welcome! Post anytime you need help! :)